# Cannot remove Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

Already done:

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

So symlink successfully removed from sites-enabled directory. But i still can see that test page. What's wrong? Shouldn't i see an error instead?

Comment: Can you please post the output for `apachectl -S` ?

Comment: VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

Answer (score 2):

The Apache code (`httpd.h file`, in particular) sets a default location of documents, which *can* be overwritten by the [`DocumentRoot` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot). Depending on the installation, the Apache source code includes lines like the following:

```
#ifndef HTTPD_ROOT
#define HTTPD_ROOT "/usr/local/apache"
#endif

#ifndef DOCUMENT_LOCATION
#define DOCUMENT_LOCATION  HTTPD_ROOT "/htdocs"
#endif
```

Because a default installation will also generally include a default `index.html` (and also default in the permissions settings to allow access the relevant directory), you *can* still be served a default page *even if* you remove all of the default sites. In order to prevent this, in favor of an error, you will have to set a default DocumentRoot that has no "index" type file or for which permission is denied, or you will have to remove such files from the directory that your installation defaults to *in the Apache code*.

Comment: So i have only one choice - remove/rename index.html under /var/www/html?

Comment: Or change it to your own file, or deny access to `/var/www/html`, or change the [DirectoryIndex directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), or change the access controls for  `index.html`, or `a2ensite` your own default site setting a different `DocumentRoot` ....

Comment: Amazing, thanks! This is the first accurate answer I found! I also found out myself that removing `<Directory /var/www>...</Directory>` from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is an effective workaround.