# Apache serves disabled virtualhost to chromium instead of correct one

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, google-chrome, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Apache server in an local Ubuntu 18.04 test environment. In `/var/www` I have the folders `html`containing the default site and `wordpress` containing a Wordpress installation. I created a virtualhost for Wordpress and disabled the default site:

```
$ ll /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 24 15:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Feb 24 15:55 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Feb 18 21:49 wordpress.conf -> ../sites-available/wordpress.conf
```

The Wordpress virtualhost looks as follows

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf 
<VirtualHost localhost:8000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and the ports as follows

```
cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf 
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 8000

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

After all these changes I restarted the apache. When I call `localhost:8000` in Firefox it displays the Wordpress instance as expected. When I call it within Chromium it displays the default page from `/var/www/html`. I deleted all caches in Chromium and even reinstalled it - still the same result. 
Even when I change the default page these changes are reflected in the Chromium output, so this is not just a caching issue.

How the heck can Chromium see a disabled virtualhost on a port a different virtualhost should be shown? Especially since everything works fine with Firefox?

Just checking that port 8000 is not used anywhere else...

```
$ grep -rnw '/etc/apache2/' -e '8000'
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:5:Listen 8000
/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf:1:<VirtualHost localhost:8000>
```

I'm really confused. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/790362/256540

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that doesn't really solve the problem. When I for example move the `html` folder Chromium doesn't display the default page anymore,  but still doesn't display the correct one.